# Edit revisions - possibility to hide a revision for users with the Edit priviledge (2000+ rep)

Tags: feature-request, edits, revisions-list

I remember when there was an option here - a checkbox - saying "***minor revision***". Such revision would not be visible in revisions history (I think).

Now, I don't particulary miss that feature, however here and there I come across a situation where I'll edit a post because it contains ***private data*** (e-mails, usernames, passwords even ...).

In such cases, wouldn't it be wise to allow people with 2000+ reputation with the right to directly edit a post to mark such edit as "hidden", so people won't be able to see previous private credentials anymore in history?

I hope I understand it right that reviews history is visible to anyone?

Comment: In those rare cases, shouldn't you simply flag the question for a moderator ? *Argh... I hate this big "Add Comment" button...*

Comment: @dystroy hmm, I didn't think of that option, perhaps it could work as a solution :)

Comment: @dystroy Just be glad it's not "ADD COMMENT".

Comment: There never was a "minor revision" checkbox. There is however the quick edit, which means that if the same user edits a post multiple times within five minutes (and nobody else does), those edits get rolled into one revision.

Comment: @balpha ah, my mistake then (the older, the wiser... works the opposite for me it would seem :D) ... thx for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is already possible, the tool to hard delete revisions is available to SE employees. Just flag for moderator attention and we'll forward it to someone who can remove the private information.

Such hard deletion cannot be reviewed by the community, and there is no way to combine proper review of such actions with actually making the private data unavailable. Due to this I strongly doubt this ability will ever be available to moderator, or even the community at large.

Comment: i would rather like to see that privilege to 20k user